# Drupal 7: How to use checkboxes values in Views filter

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, drupal-views

How can i use the values (0/1) given by the checkboxes created in a content type to create a filter within Views?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: wel, i'm creating a content type, so the customer can add images.
in this content type manage fields, i have several check boxes so the customer can decide where the images are shown, i which Views.
This way, i dont need to create 15 different content types to show images at the right place.
As a solution, i created a text field which hold a number and this number i use in views to decide of its to be shown... but this seems so tupid since checkboxes exist...
Hope i'm clear enough in my explenation...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way of doing this is looking into [Entities](http://drupal.org/project/entity) with a display mode and [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds).

Each display mode has a template in which you can choose to output the image according to the checkbox value.